# Keeping table cell from resizing in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, tablecell, css-tables

I have a table (I use it for my main layout) with a table cell that is only 20px high. The next cell is a rowspan of 2, that contains my main content. In firefox it isnt a problem at all. It stays at 20px (It's important because it is the bottom of the logo and just above the menu). In internet explorer, the cell decides not to stay at 20px high.

I am doing eveything I can think of (stylesheet, inline style and JavaScript). There has to be a way that I can keep it from resizing depending on the content of the page.

Here is the address of the page in question: http://www.rat-pack.com/Members.php

Comment: Its looking like an image problem to me. It appears that your images do not have any transparency. Try saving all of your background images a jpegs and see if that solves your problem. This was fixed in ie 9 but has been a pain for a while. If changing your images is not something you can do, try implementing one of many png fixes and see if this helps. Good luck.

Comment: No, you are missing the point of the question. BTW... the background images are pngs with transparency. Look at the page again in FF then again in IE.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is nothing you are doing wrong, it relates to how IE handles locations and table attributes

Try the following

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

if you use JS to detect what browser is being run, you can create a custom style sheet for each, which is how you work around browser limitations

Best of luck to you